# Android XML animation headache

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

My head is hurting like hell because of this. I have got an app that has a two buttons. Once I click the first button an animation plays between the activity switch. Works flawless.

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation, R.anim.animation2);
```

animation.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="100%p"
    android:toXDelta="0"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

animation2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXDelta="0"
    android:toXDelta="-50%p"
    android:duration="500"/>
```

The second activity slides in from the right with this animation. Exactly how I want it.

Now for my second button the third activity has to slide in from the left, the exact opposite.

What do I need to change in the anim xml's ?

Answer (score 0):

Just create another two animation XML files with the opposite values, like this:

animation1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

animation3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Then, just use in RunTime, after `startActivity()`, with:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation1, R.anim.animation3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this xml for sliding the activity from left

animation_slide_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

animation_slide_left_two.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="100"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

To use it in button to slide in the acitivity from left

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation_slide_left, R.anim.animation_slide_left_two);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

animation3.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="500"/>
```

animation4.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="50%p"
android:duration="500"/>
```

and onBackPressed:

animation5.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="50%p"
android:toXDelta="0"
android:duration="500"/>
```

animation6.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fromXDelta="0"
android:toXDelta="-100%p"
android:duration="500"/>
```

For the anm3 and anm4 you'll do this:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation3, R.anim.animation4);
```

For the back pressed:

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animation5, R.anim.animation6);
```

Happy Coding :)